# Why does my Twisted service quit when I close the terminal session I started it from?

Tags: python, linux, terminal, twisted, daemon

I am running a Twisted application with the following command:

```
twistd -y service.py
```

The code looks like this:

```
from twisted.web.server import Site
from twisted.application import service, internet
from twisted.web.resource import Resource

class WebRoot(Resource):
    isLeaf = True
    def render_GET(self, request):
        return "web resource".encode("utf-8")

application = service.Application("testapp")
root = internet.TCPServer(8084, Site(WebRoot()))
root.setServiceParent(application)
```

The command starts the application as a daemon, and I am then able to enter other commands into the terminal session with no issue. However, if I close the terminal session, the program stops running. I don't understand why this is happening to a daemonic service such as this, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try a simple, self-contained, complete example: http://sscce.org/ (ie, what's the simplest `service.py` for which you observe this)

Comment: Sure. I have edited the main post to include some example code.

Comment: Thanks!  That rules out my first guess. :)  What OS, shell, terminal emulator?  And what versions of Twisted and Python?

Comment: I'm using Bluehost's version of Linux:

    3.10.0-714.10.2.lve1.4.66.el6h.x86_64

with jailshell, and Coda 2 to access it. 

Twisted 17.5.0 on top of Python 3.4.3

Comment: I wonder if Bluehost kills processes when you log out of the shell.  I can't find a lot of information about the details of jailshell but what I see doesn't suggest it is responsible for this behavior.  It might make sense to ask Bluehost support about this behavior.  It seems like that's the most likely cause.

Comment: give a try to [immortal](https://immortal.run) In this case you don't need to demonize it, immortal will take care of keeping the process up and running at least during your session is open